# Facebook Open Graph object not displayed as desired

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have defined an action and an object for my FB app. The object is mandatory for the action, and it contains 4 important properties, but one property of them is a string-array which can contain many items (for eg. 12 items).

When I'm designing my Graph object in the Dashboard, the UI looks nice, all properties are displayed in the "Preview" section, and of my 12 items of a specific property, 2 is displayed and there is a "Show all" linkbutton.

[image]

These wodcontent's are very important for my object, without them the action tells nothing for other people.

My problem is that when I'm defining how shall my action (which refers/points to the aforementioned object) look like, then I can see that OBJECT_TITLE is hardcodedly displayed, and there are 4 captions fields which I can define what to display.

[image]

Is it possible to somehow display my nice object preview-UI for the action? So when an action performed I see the object displayed as it was previewed in the Object's Dashboard settings page, and not only display the title of the object and 4 optional caption fields.

My 2nd question is that is it possible to display the wodcontent property with multiple lines? That would help reading-clarity really much.

Comment: Have you tried to use _custom formatting_ in the caption fields of your action to display the object properties?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/template/  By reading the doc, I found none of them to be helpful in this case, or am I wrong?